# LVM2 : Failing to pvcreate a block device

Tags: lvm

I'm trying to make use of the *LVM2* functionality in linux (Centos6.0).
When trying to make the first step of defining a PV on a specific block device, I get the following error message:

```
[root@localhost /] pvcreate /dev/sdb
```

**Can't open /dev/sdb exclusively.  Mounted filesystem?**

*/dev/sdb* is not mounted and its partition table was deleted.
I should mention also that */dev/sdb* used to represent a larger block device (about 4 times larger) and was reduced by configuration of hardware raid (I split the hd to 4 in the raid controller).

Has anyone ever encountered this error before and knows how to take it from here?

Answer (score 17):

Maybe device-mapper is 'stealing' this device. Try this:

```
[root@host ~]# dmsetup ls
sdb     (253, 2)
VolGroup00-LogVol01     (253, 1)
VolGroup00-LogVol00     (253, 0)
```

If you find sdb device listed as above example, remove it using dmsetup and create the physical volume:

```
[root@host ~]# dmsetup remove sdb

[root@host ~]# pvcreate /dev/sdb
Physical volume "/dev/sdb" successfully created
```

Comment: I had to use `dmsetup remove_all -f` to unlock my situation

Answer (score 0):

`[root@localhost /]` `pvcreate -vvvvv /dev/sdb`

Could ouput more details.
and you could use *lsof -L* to check if the block device is opened by other process.